# How can I convert textfield input from 1234567891234 to 1234-56-789-1234 in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this textfield

```
<div class="name">
   <label for="name">NSN</label>
   <input type="text" id="NSN" name="name" />
</div>
```

I know how to add a coma to number input using this Jquery

```
$("#NSN").on('keyup', function(){
var n = parseInt($(this).val().replace(/\D/g,''),10);
$(this).val(n.toLocaleString());
});
```

but how do I add a - after the 4th number,  after the 6th, and after the 9th.

Comment: What have you already tried that isn't working? Have you tried [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=formatting+numbers+in+javascript&oq=formatting+numbers&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.4439j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: No one can give a complete solution for you. There are lot of solutions, available anyways. See how need to ask a question here for better help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: A search term you might want to try is "input mask"

Comment: @DanielBeck thank you. I did not know the term for it. That was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added these files

```
<script src="../Js/inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="../Js/inputmask.extensions.js"></script>
<script src="../Js/inputmask.numeric.extensions.js"></script>
```

and the following code to set the masking of NSN

```
var NSNselector = document.getElementById("NSN");
var im = new Inputmask("9999-999-9999-999");
im.mask(NSNselector);
```

see the following link for further information on masking.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery.inputmask

Comment: _"see the following link for further information on masking"_ ... where? you haven't added a link!
And where do these 3 'inputmask' .js files come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<p>Masked on the keyup event</p>
<input type="text" id="phone" placeholder="1234-56-789-1234"/>
```

and then:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('phone').addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
    e.target.value = x[1] + '-' + x[2] + '-' + x[3]+ '-' + x[4];
  });
</script>
```